# biber cannot find my .bib file

Tags: biblatex, biber

(Please bear with me I am new here so hope this question is not off-topic as my previous-first one was).

I am using TeXShop, biblatex and biber, but my biber does not seem to be able to locate my .bib file in the location specified in the path. If put the .bib in the local folder (that is in the folder where my .tex is) it finds it but if I use the central bibliography file (needing a relative location) it doesn't.
Here is what I am doing:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[british]{babel} 
\usepackage{csquotes} 
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{/home/ifuchs/Documents/Work/Gender.bib}
\usepackage[colorlinks, allcolors=blue, breaklinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\autocite{myKey}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

> ```
> INFO - Found 44 citekeys in bib section 0
> INFO - Processing section 0
> INFO - Looking for bibtex format file '/home/ifuchs/Documents/Work/Gender.bib' for section 0
> ERROR - Cannot find '/home/ifuchs/Documents/Work/Gender.bib'!
> INFO - ERRORS: 1
> ```

Comment: Are you sure it is `/home/...` not `/Users/...`?

Comment: Well, you are right. Apparently it seems to be working with /Users/.... Thanks!

Comment: That is the standard path name for home directories on OS-X

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is due to an incorrect specification of the file path.

Comment: Still: don't do this.  Find out where BibTeX expects to find files and put it there, or at least symlink your file to that spot.  `kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFHOME` will give you a location like `/Users/ifuchs/texmf` (or something; I don't use a Mac), then `mkdir -p /Users/ifuchs/texmf/bibtex/bib` and put it there, or use `ln -s` to create a symlink pointing to your `.bib` file.